# "Er ist alt, 99 Jahre" - Eine nachgestellte Gradangabe?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Er ist alt, 99 Jahre
> Der Fluss ist breit, 50 Meter.

Umgestellt sind diese Grad-(oder Maß?)Angaben sicher Adverben. Es sind keine Adjektive, und meiner Vermutung nach auch keine Nomen, also habe ich ausgeschlossen, dass es sich um eine Apposition oder eine satzwertige Adjektivphrase handeln könnte. Zumal Appositionen sowieso ein Nomen als Bezugswort brauchen, kein Adjektiv wie "breit" oder "alt".

Ist es eine Ellipse, wie es Janka in den Kommentaren vorschlägt?

Andere Beispiele:

> Der Berg ist hoch, sehr hoch.
> Sie lief weit, 100 Kilometer.

Sind es umgangssprachlich genutzte Konstruktionen, bei denen eine Spezifikation durch eine Art Anfügung nachgetragen werden?

Comment: '99 Jahre' ist sicher keine Gradangabe sondern eine Zeitspanne. Aber was genau ist die Frage?

Comment: Hallo planetmaker. Die Frage ist, was diese Konstruktion ist. Wie man sie nennt.

Comment: Wieso ist 99 Jahre eine "Zeitspanne"? Ich kann 99 Jahre durch "sehr", "ziemlich" oder "ordentlich" ersetzen, nur um ein paar Beispiele zu nennen. Wieso also nicht Gradangabe? Diese Meinung kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Eine Zeitspanne würde ich mittels eines Adverbials ausdrücken.

Comment: Ist das nicht einfach eine Wiederholung mit Ellipse? *Er ist alt, 99 Jahre (alt).*

Comment: Also "Er ist alt, (er ist) 99 Jahre (alt)"?

Comment: Im ersten kann *insgesamt* eingesetzt werden, was hoffentlich an dem Zusammenhang von *all* und *alt* liegt, vgl. *ultimately, all-to-gether, all told, all said and done*, vielleicht auch *also, alleso*. Pfeifer spricht von einer "Partizipialform ie. *\*alnos* ‘ausgewachsen, vollständig, komplett". Nicht sicher.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist das überhaupt keine deutsche Konstruktion. Die entsprechende Wendung existiert im Französischen, vielleicht hat sie dort einen Namen.

Comment: @KilianFoth Also ungrammatikalisch. Danke für Deine Meinung

Answer (score 2):

Ja, eine "Apposition", laut [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)

> ein Untertyp von Attributen (Satzgliedteilen, Beifügungen) [...], die sich mit einem Substantiv oder Pronomen verbinden

kann es nicht sein, da der Zusatz ja nicht Bezug auf das Substantiv oder Pronomen selbst nimmt, sondern auf das Adjektiv.

Deine Beispiele ähneln [freien Prädikativa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Freie_Pr%C3%A4dikativa), allerdings sind diese

> Satzglieder, die dem Subjekt oder Objekt des Satzes eine Eigenschaft zusätzlich zusprechen. Dieser Typ des Prädikativs wird auch als Depiktiv bezeichnet.

Das passt also auch nicht 100%ig.

Ich würde diese Konstruktion entweder als "Zusatz"

> Das Komma trennt nachgestellte Zusätze ab. Wenn der Satz danach weitergeht, steht auch am Ende des Zusatzes ein Komma (= paariges Komma) ‹§ 77 (2)›.
>
> Zum Beispiel
>
> - Das ist Michael, mein Bruder.
> - Das Auto, Massenverkehrsmittel und Statussymbol zugleich, hat das Gesicht unserer Städte nachhaltig geprägt.
> - Johannes Gutenberg, der Erfinder der Buchdruckerkunst, wurde in Mainz geboren.

*Quelle: [Duden, Rechtschreibregeln, D109](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D109)*

oder als "nachgestellte Erläuterung"

> Das Komma trennt nachgestellte Erläuterungen ab. (Solche Erläuterungen werden häufig durch und zwar, nämlich, z. B., insbesondere oder ähnliche Wörter und Fügungen eingeleitet.)
>
> Zum Beispiel
>
> - Sie liest viel, vor allem Krimis.
> - Das Schiff verkehrt wöchentlich einmal, und zwar sonntags.
> - Das Schiff verkehrt nur in der Hauptsaison, das heißt im Sommer.
> - Wir müssen etwas unternehmen, und das bald.
> - Es gibt vier Jahreszeiten, nämlich Frühling, Sommer, Herbst und Winter.

*Quelle: [Duden, Rechtschreibregeln, D111](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D111)*

einordnen. Interessanterweise sind alle Beispiele für Zusätze oben solche für Substantive, und nicht für Adjektive, und im Gegensatz zu "99 Jahre alt" oder "50 m breit" kann man die nachgestellten Erläuterungen nicht in den Satz hineinverschieben (mit Ausnahme von "Wir müssen *bald* etwas unternehmen").

Trotzdem bin ich der Meinung, dass man in Deinem Beispielfall sowohl

> Er ist alt, 99 Jahre.

als auch

> Er ist alt, und zwar 99 Jahre.

schreiben könnte.